# Docker Kong container stops after migration

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, kong, api-gateway

I have a nodejs API running in a docker container and I want to use Kong as API-Gateway. Kong will be running in another docker container. When I start API container and Kong container using docker-compose, Kong container throws an error saying;

```
kong       | stack traceback:
kong       |    [C]: in function 'assert'
kong       |    /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:160: in function 'init'
kong       |    init_by_lua:3: in main chunk
kong       | 2018/02/07 11:14:17 [warn] postgres database 'kong' is missing migration: (response-transformer) 2016-05-04-160000_resp_trans_schema_changes
kong       | nginx: [error] init_by_lua error: /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:160: [postgres error] the current database schema does not match this version of Kong. Please run `kong migrations up` to update/initialize the database schema. Be aware that Kong migrations should only run from a single node, and that nodes running migrations concurrently will conflict with each other and might corrupt your database schema!
```

docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  couchdb:
    image: couchdb
    container_name: e-db
    ports:
      - 5984:5984
    environment:
      COUCHDB_USER: admin
      COUCHDB_PASSWORD: admin

  api:
    image: e-api
    container_name: e-api
    entrypoint: ./docker-entrypoint.sh couchdb 5984
    build: .
    command: npm run dev
    depends_on:
      - couchdb
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

  kong-db:
    image: postgres:alpine
    container_name: kong-db
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: kong
      POSTGRES_DB: kong

  kong:
    image: kong:0.12.1-alpine
    container_name: kong
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - kong-db
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
      - 8443:8443
      - 8001:8001
    environment:
      KONG_PG_HOST: kong-db
      KONG_DATABASE: postgres
    command: kong migrations up

  kong-ui:
    image: pgbi/kong-dashboard
    container_name: kong-ui
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 8089:8080
    depends_on:
      - kong
```

So, After getting that error, I added "command: kong migrations up" to kong service. This time it does the migrations. But after migrations, kong container stops and I can't restart it.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Your kong service depends on Kong-db. However, it will kong will not wait until your database is up and running.

Answer (score 0):

kong:0.12.1 supports only postgresql 9.5+ as datastore. So see to that you link the kong with the compatible version of postgresql.

And if you are pointing multiple kongs to same db and same user, then see to that the kong schemas match.